# Exlude time test

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, googletest

Hello i have some class for example "Math":
header file:

```
class Math
{
public:
    Math(void);
    double returnPi();
    ~Math(void);
};
```

and cpp file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Math.h"

Math::Math(void)
{   Sleep(500)  ;}

Math::~Math(void)
{   Sleep(500)  ;}

double Math::returnPi()
{   Sleep(1000) ;
    return 3.14159265;
}
```

also i have test of this file:

```
#include "..\gtest\gtest.h"
#include "Math.h"

TEST(Speed, Math)
{
    Math *m=new Math();
    EXPECT_LT(3.14,m->returnPi());
}
```

when i run this test i see that test passed and time of this test is 1500ms, how i can exclude from total test time, time elapsed on creating class?

Comment: not sure about your test framework, can you not pass in an instance of `Math` rather than creating within the test?

Comment: Nim it is example, in real project i need create example class for each  test, and after that testing his function

Comment: hmm, so you cannot pass in an instance, and you cannot use a global, well there is no way you can avoid the cost of the creation in your test method - AFAIK. Why don't you create a specific test which only creates the instance - record the time for that, and deduct from all the other tests?

Comment: i know about it, but maybe exists some way to exclude time of execution for some function(constructor, destructor..), without change code in library

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?

```
#include "..\gtest\gtest.h"
#include "Math.h"

Math math;

TEST(Speed, Math)
{
    Math *m=&math;
    EXPECT_LT(3.14,m->returnPi());
}
```

Comment: No, i need create class in all test case

Answer (score 0):

Create a test fixture that constructs your Math class, then make your tests use it. GTest will create a new fixture for each test.

```
class MathTest : public ::testing::Test
{
     Math* math;
     virtual void SetUp()
     {      
         math = new Math();
     }

     virtual void TearDown()
     {
        delete math;
     }
};

TEST_F(MathTest, OperatorTest)
{
    EXPECT_LT(3.14,math->returnPi());

}
```

But really I think your question is a bit flawed you shouldn't exclude that from total test time. If you are trying to profile particular operations you should use a timer and output the elapsed time for what you are profiling. Total test time should be how long it took to run your tests (and that of course includes setup time).